# Predicting time interval based on statistics

Tags: probability

Let's say, we have some random event. We also have a hist of time intervals between two events, based on statistical data. For example, a frequency distribution:

```
[100,30,15,10,7,6,5,5,4,4]
```

Each bin value corresponds to length of time interval between two events. 1st bin corresponds to `[0,1)` seconds, 2nd bin is for `[1,2)` seconds, 3rd is for `[2,3)` secs and so on.

How would I predict the time that it might take to get K events?

If we normalize and cumulatively add the bin's value, we can get a probability hist, each bin's value is `P(one event in time < bin's edge)`. But how would I get such a probability hist for K events? `P(K events in time < bin's edge)`

Comment: Anyway, read this first http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process

Comment: Google for negative binomial distribution. In addition to Wikipedia, one good site is
http://www.randomservices.org/random/.